# C++ can't compile code using PROCESSENTRY32

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to compile simple lines of code but I'm getting C2664 Error code.

```cpp
#include <TlHelp32.h>

PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { 0 };

if (wcscmp(pe32.something, something) == 0)
```

Error:

> int wcscmp(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t

The definition of `wcscmp()` is:

```cpp
_Check_return_
_ACRTIMP int __cdecl wcscmp(
    _In_z_ wchar_t const* _String1,
    _In_z_ wchar_t const* _String2
    );
```

I can't use `PROCESSENTRY32W` because then `Process32First()` breaks because it needs `PROCESSENTRY32`.

How could I change this to make it compilable?

Comment: Are you building this with `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` defined? Alternately, use `PROCESSENTRY32W` (with a `W` at the end) to signify the wide-char version of the struct.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I could use PROCESSENTRY32W but then Process32First breaks because it need PROCESSENTRY32

Comment: @user17909291 use `Process32FirstW` then

Comment: @Genjutsu didn't knew it existed. Thank you

Comment: "*Solved by Genjutsu and Steve Friedl ... Solution: ...*" - the solution should be posted as a proper answer, not as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Note that you're going to run into this issue with many of the API functions, so figuring out how to define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` (one is for the C runtime, the other is for Win32, I don't recall which is which) will make *everything* wide-char, and that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PROCESSENTRY32W` instead of `PROCESSENTRY32`.

Use `Process32FirstW` instead of `Process32First`.